# Is it possible to hyperlink mail text to an Exe residing at a remote system in through C# windows application (mail sent through SMTP server)?

Tags: windows

Sending a mail through my windows application to a person "asking him to log on to another windows application that is installed in a remote server to work on it". In the mail content, i would like to have a hyperlink that will directly take him to that windows application!

Comment: What? Explain the question, please - it is very difficult to understand.

Comment: Sending a mail through my windows application to a person "asking him to log on to another windows application that is installed in a remote server to work on it". In the mail content, i would like to have a hyperlink that will directly take him to that windows application!

Comment: Didn't you already ask this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424159/hyperlink-text-in-mail-content-generated-in-smtp-in-c-windows-application

Comment: Kev, yes but the 'remote system' concept is not included in that Question!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not use about your question, but if you need to link to a EXE file on another computer like:

Computer A has a EXE file, computer A sends a email to Computer B, with a hyperlink to the EXE file
Computer B runs the EXE file on own computer, or make Computer A run the EXE file

Sorry, but that is not possible. If you need to make a EXE file run on a email, just must send it as a attachment, and the user must save the exe file, and run it - you can't do anything automatic like that.

Comment: In this case, i just want the hyperlink to navigate to the target Windows Exe that is in another server but not available in the receiving persons system!!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you like to:

- send an e-mail to another user.
- the mail contains a link to a (web?) application, which enables the user to login

If you want a web applciation, you could build one using for example ASP.NET or PHP.

If you want a standalone (EXE) application, the user can download the exe file and execute it on the other machine. In this case FTP is the preferred protocol for that.

On the limited license remark. If the license allows you to share the application on the web, you can possibly distribute time limited licenses. But I still think, the better solution will be to access the application through a web interface. In that case you can chose how many concurrent users you allow to use the app.

Comment: Fine, I have only limited number of license for the Exes

Comment: Ok, does the license allow you to share the exe on the web? If not, you can't do this unfortunately.

Comment: Great, i am not sure about, the application is an windows based exe. Is it accessible through web interface?